# Turn Generator to JSON JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, generator

I recently started taking a look at JS and Node.js. However I did't fully enjoy writing callback-style code, so I started writing a little framework for Node. I have completed it but now I am trying to make it work on multi-core with Node Cluster. The problem is, I can't send a generator from the master to a worker, since my framework is based on generators and I have to make the workers run the generators. How would I turn the generator object to JSON that I could then send to my workers or some other approach for sending the generator to the worker? I have tried just turning the generator to JSON but it resulted with an empty object without the next or throw method.

Here is how an example of what ping-pong would look like:

```
Thr.setNumCPUs(require("os").CPUS.length-1) 
//not to have one extra because of the master
function ping(times){
    var chan = new Thr.Chan();//create new channel
    Thr.spwn(function* (){//start a new thr, on any of the cpus
       var chan2 = pong(chan);
       for (var i= 0;i < times;i++){
          yield* chan.send("ping, for the "+(i+1)+" timth");
          //wait untill chan is empty, then send a value
          console.log(yield* chan2.rcv());
          //wait until received the value
       }
       chan.close();
       //close the channel so now on can access it
     }  ,[]);
}


function pong(chan){
   var chan2 = new Thr.Chan();
   Thr.spwn(function* (){
       var i = 0;
       while (!chan.closed){
          console.log(yield* chan.rcv());
           yield* chan2.send("pong, for the "+(++i)+" timth");
       }
       chan2.close();
   }  ,[]);
   return chan2;
}
if (cluster.isMaster){
    ping(5);
}
```

Comment: The native JSON parser can't evaluate functions in JSON, they're not valid.

Comment: I know that but, is there another way to parse it, or send the result a different way to the worker. I cannot even get the function*.next to a string.

Comment: You'll have to implement your own JSON parser (!)

Comment: Well I probably don't have the time to do that and I can not even get the generator.next to a string.

Comment: What happens when you try to convert the function to a string. Seems to work for me.

Comment: If you don't like callbacks, why not use promises?

Comment: because their not multi-core(could be) but generators are nicer than promises(my opinion).

Comment: and for Blindman, I get function(){ [native code] } when I turn it to a string, which I can't parse.

Comment: If its a native function then should it not be available on the worker.

Comment: I will test that, I am just not sure if every generator shares the same next function.

Comment: So now you want to "call" the `pong` on a different cluster node?

Comment: It will automatically be scheduled on a different worker because the main cluster keeps track of all the alive couritines on each cpu.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem now? Also, what is that `Thr` lib, I couldn't find any?

Comment: Thr lib, I wrote it but I haven't posted it yet and I haven't finished writing the multi-core version of it, that was why I posted this question, the code in the example works on a single core, though.

Comment: I finished making the library execute on multiple cores, now I have to implement channels on multiple cores

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a format for serialising data, not executable functions*. In order to pass a generator as JSON you'd actually need to iterate through the generator to produce all the values, store them in something like an array and then simply add that array to the object you're turning into JSON. This would probably remove any benefit from using a generator but it could easily be done.

I've not had a chance to use cluster yet, but I got the impression that you could use it to simply run different entire node instances as a cluster, thus removing any need to manually fork processes to make use of multiple processors.

If you like using generators for async code there's a library called `co` which does just that, which you might have just reinvented.

Comment: Only for non deterministic generators. Generators still have toString() and can be reconstructed with  `GeneratorFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(function*(){}).constructor;` passing the function as json is easy. Adding state info would be easy as well. Generators are just objects after all.

Comment: well close, but I have a different approach than using generators combined with promises, my library has channels, a lot like Golang and CO isn't multi-core, the library I made works perfectly fine on one core.

Comment: Blindman, is there also a way of getting the code for the function of the generator that I can turn to JSON after the generator object is created, because the library accepts a generator object and not a function*, I could of course change the library so it accepts the function and the arguments, many thanks.

Comment: A generator that uses data in a closure would be non-deterministic, such as those given in the ping-pong example.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually know found an answer to my question after researching generators and at Blindman's comments. The first thing I have to do is create the constructor for the generator:`var GeneratorFunctionConstructor =  Object.getPrototypeOf(function*(){}).constructor`. Then when I send I job to one of the workers I create a JSON object with the function* as a String and the arguments passed to it. Then I create a new Generator object with the constructor by getting the args of the function*, and the function* body. Next I call `Generator.apply(this,args)` and start executing it asynchronously.

Comment: Notice you'll loose all closure variables through that. It would be more sensible to instantiate your framework multiple times (on each cluster node), and only pass data around not generators.

Comment: that's a good idea but how do you know which generator to pass what data.

Comment: Depends on your code and what it is doing. I assume you're doing inter-process-communication via channels anyway? Then one approach could be to just create all generators everywhere and only pass data to those which should do work. Or if you are concerned what to instantiate where, and need to do it dynamically, then put all generator functions in a huge object in which they can be identified by their property name.

Comment: does that mean when I create a new generator I call the generator that is already saved in a data structure across all threads.

Comment: You can either store generators themselves or the generator functions that create them in your datastructures. Use what you need. We might be able to better help you when you could post the relevant parts of your code (as a simple example, maybe a ping-pong between two cluster nodes)

Comment: added a ping-pong example